# How to make picture to have a clickmode ability

Tags: c#, wpf

Goal:
When you click on the arrow picture you should execute a specific C# code. The arrow need to have a clickmode or similiar.

Problem:
I do not know how to do in order to make these arrow pictures to be acting as a click mode.

xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="usercontrol_bokning.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Background="White" Margin="-127,0,-777,-316">
    <ListView x:Name="lvw_aktivitet" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single" Height="337" Margin="217,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="356" SelectionChanged="lvw_aktivitet_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Tid" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tid}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Aktivitet" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Aktivitet}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left"  />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Total platser" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Total_platser}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"  />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Bokade" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Bokade}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"  />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Drop in" Width="auto"  >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Block.TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Drop_in}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Calendar x:Name="cdate_left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedDatesChanged="cdate_left_SelectedDatesChanged"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_idag" Content="Idag" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="217,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btn_idag_Click"/>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="420" Margin="603,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="589">
        <TabItem Header="Bokade">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <ListView x:Name="lvw_bokade" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="335" Margin="10,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="561">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
                <Button Content="Ny plats" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Avbokade">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,1,0,-1"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <Label x:Name="lbl_instruktor" Content="Instruktör: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1009,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Image x:Name="bild_arrow_left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="302,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Source="C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\left.jpg" />
    <Image x:Name="bild_arrow_right" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="326,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" Source="C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\right.jpg"/>
    <Label x:Name="lbl_DisplayDateBySelection" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="396,119,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show your XAML for images? Do I understand well that you want to make them clickable, like `Button`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct about the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to click on the `Image` as you do with `Button` then you use `Button` and just change its `Template` to be your `Image`. This way you have all functionality of a `Button` with looks of an `Image`

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Image Source="..."/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

you can bind `Button.Command` or add `Click` event handler